# Unable to resolve module `react-navigation'

Tags: android, react-native

native. I want to active StackNavigator in App.js file. Please note my App.js file in different folder named 'app' and under app there is components folder under this I want to make all component file. here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import Attendence from "./components/Attendence";

const Application = StackNavigator(
{
 Home: { screen: Attendence }
},
{
 navigationOptions: {
   header: false
 }
```

}
);

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {
  return <Application />;
 }
}
```

Comment: run yarn add react-navigation.     or   npm install react-navigation --save.  in your terminal

Comment: I have already run this not working

Comment: re run nom install than in your project directory! sometime its just terminal directories that we mess up!

Comment: Hello If I not use react-navigation my project is working . I reinstall react-navigate not working

Comment: Body:
{"originModulePath":"F:\\React Native\\check\\app\\App.js","targetModuleName":"react-navigation","message":"Unable to resolve module `react-navigation` from `F:\\React Native\\check\\app\\App.js`: Module `react-navigation` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n I got this error all time

Comment: did you try to delete your node module folder and running. npm install --save again?

Comment: Brother Still not able to solve I again install node package. Does it occurs because of my "react-native": "0.55.4", and "react-navigate": "^0.6.0"

Comment: try resintalling react native

Comment: npm install --save react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.11 I install several times not working I have found a project in github in react-native that is working but when I try to install in my project I got error

Comment: I said uninstall your react native and reinstall new react native!..  and if this is someone elses project then see the packageJSON file to see the version of react-native used for it! and try to install that!

Comment: Brother now react-navigation work .  But I have a question that how many dependency I can add in package.json . now  react-navigate working but another dependency not work

Comment: please accept my answer and do post some pictures of your package.json and also the errors in the question so we all can help you the easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have **downloaded an old project** ! it means you are about to tackle different node dependency packages errors on the route to get it running!

> **My tips** to get your self saved from errors are like this

**1:** go into the package.json
**2:** note down every dependency names and versions
   (the reason why to do that is simple ! you gonna need some awesome code that were in old version is now deprecated in new versions of those libs running!) so installing old ones would help you with that

**3:** if the point 2 does not work! please do check the version number of react native that you have and the one the real coder of the app used! and install the older version of react native in newer version there are some new things than old versions!

**PRO TIP:::** **USE YARN**

> instead of **NPM** to save your self from the problems!

Comment: Here is my Package.json file
    "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
     "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }, 
How many dependancy I can add since if I add 5 dependency i got error